# Is it possible (how) to copy certificates from my desktop to my laptop?

Tags: certificate, active-directory, azure-activedirectory

I have a desktop with certificates installed which allow me to sign into Azure DevOps. I do not have those certificates on my laptop, but I want to get them there so that I can also sign into Azure DevOps on my laptop.

Currently, when I attempt to log into Azure DevOps on my laptop, I type in my email address and am confronted with:

> Active Directory Federation Service
>
> An error occurred No valid client certificate found in the request. No
> valid certificates found in the user's certificate store. Please try
> again choosing a different authentication method.

I don't even reach the point where I type my email address.

Comment: How were these certificates originally installed? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

To transfer certificates between Windows computers :

In the exporting computer :

- Run *Start > Manage computer certif‌icates*
- Locate your certificate, which is perhaps in the section
  "Personal > Certificates"
- Right-click the certificate and select *All Tasks > Export ...*
- Select in the wizard your export format and select a file.

In the importing computer :

- Run *Start > Manage computer certif‌icates*
- Right-click the store from which you found the  certificate, possibly "Personal > Certificates", and select
  *All Tasks > Import ...*
- Navigate to the certificate file and import it.

Comment: I assume I just have to transfer the certificates one by one until I find the one that ADFS is requiring? There's so many in there.

Comment: Transferring all of them would be too dangerous, you need to find the certificate.

Comment: You won't generally have that many certificates within `Personal > Certificates`, which is where it will be. All the other certificates outside of that folder won't be relevant to what you're doing, they're related to the local system. 
Also since you want to import it to another machine as is, if you're prompted about the Private key then you need to select `Yes, export the private key` when prompted, otherwise it likely won't work as needed.